# Navigation Controller goes to blank screen

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, uiview, uinavigationcontroller

I've developed an app using xcode 4.2 and storyboard and yesterday when I tried to build it for ios 4, I was surprised to find out that storyboard is only supported from IOS 5.
Thats not good...
So now I am working on changing my whole storyboard to XIB files which I know nothing about.
So here is my problem -
I have a navigation controller (log in screen) which (if the log is succesful) navigates to a tableview. 
Now when a row is selected I want to navigate to another view.

I created a DataView and wrote:

```
DataView *d = [[DataView alloc] initWithNibName:@"DataView" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:d animated:YES];
[d release];
```

I have an XIB file DataView.xib:
There I inserted a UIViewController which has a view and inside that a label.
And in the attribute inspector I wrote DataView in the NIB Name.

Yet, when I select a row it just goes to a blank screen.
What am I missing?

I'd realy appreciate your help.

Comment: Is your root view in the AppDelegate a UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the view controller in your NIB file.

Add a view and any subviews you may want, then make sure the File Owner on the nib is set to your view controller, then option click & drag from the view to file owner and select the view outlet.